# PHP / SQL Sexy sort field1 by status of field2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, select

Greets - I've been getting my feet wet for a while with PHP and SQL combos (adding PDO recently) and am curious if there's a more eloquent way of performing the following:

I have a table ('scans') of two [relevant] fields: IDENT and STATUS. IDENT is a text serial number, and STATUS is a specific text describing the status of the IDENT, such as 'state1', 'state2', 'state3', and so on.

The table, 'scans', is a consolidating space where IDENT may occur a number of times, either with the same STATUS, or with a different STATUS. The value of STATUS escalates, so we would start with 'status1', (where every IDENT would have at least this STATUS) and end up with 'status5' (where not every IDENT would have this STATUS), and of course there would be some collection of various other STATUSes in the middle.

Although it is possible to have a lower STATUS for a particular IDENT occur later in time (higher row number), the priority is always given to the higher STATUS name, which is why my little looping method below is functional.

Right now, I'm taking this table and building a new table of IDENTS where there is only one row entry for each unique IDENT (created via SELECT DISTINCT), and then iterating some IFs to populate the new table's STATUS field starting with 'status1' and ending with 'status5'. As one progresses to 'status5' fewer rows get updated, but the process seems inefficient.

It works, but I have a feeling that there's a cleaner way than having to loop through, and a better process if I need to scale up the number of STATUSes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The content of your question suggests MySQL, so I added that tag. That said, I think you need a good bit more information here.

Comment: @MarcB Sorting *is* sexy!

Comment: maybe if it's going DD -> D -> C -> B

Comment: @MarcB My responses to that would be highly inappropriate!